# less items take more time to random-choose from

Tags: python

I'm creating a maze generator that has the following algorithm:

1) pick random coordinates, add the coordinates to **paths** list

2) pick random direction to move (up, down, left, rigth)

a) if I go beyond the bounds of the maze or the coordinates I moved to are already in **paths** - then delete the choses direction from directions list and go to step 2

b) if I can't go anywhere (**directions** list is empty) - then restore **directions** list and go to any position from **paths**

c) if it's ok - then go to step 2

Repeat until all posible positions are visited. Here's a part of code where the program chooses the coordinates:

```
while len(paths) < all_positions:
    if len(directions) == 0:
        row, col = random.choice(paths)
        directions = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']
    else:
        direction = random.choice(directions)

        if direction == 'up':
            if row-2 > 0 and pixels[row-2, col, 0] != 255:
                row -= 2
                # some other code
            else:
                directions.remove(direction)
        # the same for down, left and right
```

The main flaw of this algorithm, I think, is this line `row, col = random.choice(paths)` because I can pick position when I'm blocked (can't go anywhere) again. So if I have 1000x1000 maze, I could randomly pick blocked positions over and over again.

So I decided to create a list of blocked positions not to choose from. So now my code looks like this:

```
while len(paths) < all_positions:
    if len(directions) == 0:
        if [row, col] not in blocked:
            blocked.append([row, col])
        nonblocked = [x for x in paths if x not in blocked]
        row, col = random.choice(nonblocked)
        directions = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']

    else:
        direction = random.choice(directions)

        if direction == 'up':
```

But now it takes much more time to generate a maze with less possible positions to randomly choose from. The first generator takes 0.05s to generate 55x55 maze and 0.18 for 99x99. When the second one takes 1.84s for 55x55 and like forever for 99x99. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: I guess the time increase is due to building `blocked` and `nonblocked`, try making these structures `set`s

Comment: You may consider getting up to speed on a line profiler. This allows you to measure where the problem is directly, and avoid guess work. It's pretty easy to use, and is a valuable skill moving forward. See https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler

Comment: You probably don't need both `blocked` and `nonblocked` if one is the complement of the other.

Comment: @Chris_Rands could you please show me what changes do I need to make?